# SQL Query with Union Neglects rows

Tags: sql

I have am facing issue with a SQL query. When I try with part of query, it works fine for me. But when I combine it with `Union`, it skips the values which I have entered in same voucher but account number is same.

For example if I have two entries in the table with the same account number, and try to get them with this query:

```
SELECT 
    'DV-'+Convert(Varchar,VoucherNo) AS VoucherNo,
    DebitVouchersBody.AccountNo,
    AccountName,
    VoucherDate AS Date,
    DebitVouchersBody.Narration,
    Debit,
    0.00 AS Credit
FROM
    DebitVouchersBody
LEFT JOIN 
    ChartOfAccounts ON DebitVouchersBody.AccountNo = ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo
WHERE 
    DebitVouchersBody.AccountNo = '541'
```

This is working fine for me as per above query and it returns both entries.

But when I implement with `union` as described in below query, the code neglects all other rows which are having the same voucher number and having same account number. And it returns the top one row of account number if it's duplicated in the voucher. I want to get all rows no matter about account number duplicated or not.

Can you please suggest how I can resolve this?

```
SELECT 
    'SI-'+Convert(Varchar,Sales.SaleID) AS VoucherNo,
    CustomerId AS AccountNo,
    AccountName, Date, Sales.Narration,
    InvoiceAmount-InvoiceDiscount AS Debit,
    PaidAmount AS Credit
FROM
    Sales
LEFT JOIN 
    ChartOfAccounts ON Sales.CustomerId = ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo
WHERE 
    CustomerId = '541'

UNION

SELECT 
    'PI-' + CONVERT(Varchar, Purchases.PurchaseId) AS VoucherNo,
    VendorId AS AccountNo,
    AccountName, Date, Purchases.Narration,
    AmountPaid AS Debit,
    InvoiceAmount AS Credit
FROM 
    Purchases
LEFT JOIN 
    ChartOfAccounts ON Purchases.VendorId = ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo
WHERE 
    VendorId = '541'

UNION

SELECT 
    'DV-' + CONVERT(Varchar, VoucherNo) AS VoucherNo,
    DebitVouchersBody.AccountNo,
    AccountName,
    VoucherDate AS Date,
    DebitVouchersBody.Narration,
    Debit,
    0.00 AS Credit
FROM
    DebitVouchersBody
LEFT JOIN 
    ChartOfAccounts ON DebitVouchersBody.AccountNo = ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo
WHERE 
    DebitVouchersBody.AccountNo = '541'

UNION

SELECT 
    'CV-' + CONVERT(Varchar,VoucherNo) AS VoucherNo,
    CreditVouchersBody.AccountNo,
    AccountName,
    VoucherDate AS Date,
    CreditVouchersBody.Narration,
    0.00 AS Debit,
    Credit
FROM
    CreditVouchersBody
LEFT JOIN 
    ChartOfAccounts ON CreditVouchersBody.AccountNo = ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo
WHERE 
    CreditVouchersBody.AccountNo = '541'

UNION

SELECT 
    'JV-' + CONVERT(Varchar, VoucherNo) AS VoucherNo,
    JournalVouchersBody.AccountNo,
    AccountName,
    VoucherDate AS Date,
    JournalVouchersBody.Narration,
    Debit,
    Credit
FROM
    JournalVouchersBody
LEFT JOIN 
    ChartOfAccounts ON JournalVouchersBody.AccountNo = ChartOfAccounts.AccountNo
WHERE 
    JournalVouchersBody.AccountNo = '541'

UNION

SELECT 
    NULL AS VoucherNo,
    NULL AS AccountNo,
    NULL AS Name,
    NULL AS Date,
    'Opening Balance' AS Narration,
    OpeningDebit AS Debit,
    OpeningCredit AS Crdit
FROM
    ChartOfAccounts
WHERE 
    AccountNo = '541'
ORDER BY 
    Date, VoucherNo
```

Comment: `UNION` removes duplicates from the result set, `UNION ALL` does not.

Comment: Are you sure that the vendorId and customerId are also equal to 541?

Comment: Thank u very much, that worked for me, Union ALL was the point

Comment: You really must include the table name or alias in all column references

Comment: Why would you say it is necessary to include table name or alias in all column references?